# Styling Nested list elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to style alternate item in a list with a background color of gray.  However, if there are nested li elements, the styling goes wrong, and consecutive elements in the nested list get styled the same color of gray.

Any idea on how to style them alternate gray, even the nested ones, using css/jquery?

**Edit**

```
<div id='wrapper'>

<ul>

<li class='comment'><div class='aut'>the_archer</div><div class='comment-body'>Test</div><div class='timestamp'>2011-02-15 17:22:11</div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='7'>Reply</a><ul><li class='comment'><div class='aut'>great</div><div class='comment-body'>t</div><div class='timestamp'>2011-02-15 17:38:43</div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='8'>Reply</a><ul><li class='comment'><div class='aut'>test</div><div class='comment-body'>eee</div><div class='timestamp'>2011-02-15 17:40:21</div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='10'>Reply</a><ul><li class='comment'><div class='aut'>fook</div><div class='comment-body'>kkk</div><div class='timestamp'>2011-02-15 18:07:08</div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='12'>Reply</a></li></ul></li><li class='comment'><div class='aut'>Anonymouse</div><div class='comment-body'>dsdsd</div><div class='timestamp'>2011-02-15 17:44:53</div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='11'>Reply</a></li><li class='comment'><div class='aut'>bbbb</div><div class='comment-body'>bbbb</div><div class='timestamp'>2011-02-15 18:32:23</div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='14'>Reply</a></li></ul></li><li class='comment'><div class='aut'>w</div><div class='comment-body'>www</div><div class='timestamp'>2011-02-15 17:39:29</div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='9'>Reply</a></li></ul></li><li class='comment'><div class='aut'>t</div><div class='comment-body'>t</div><div class='timestamp'>2011-02-15 18:30:09</div><a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id='13'>Reply</a></li></ul>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.comment-style{background: gray;}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('ul li.comment:odd').addClass('comment-style');
```

Comment: show us what you have until now in html & css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yynSs/2/)**

Changed JQuery:

```
$('li.comment:odd').css("background-color", "gray");
$('li.comment:even').css("background-color", "white");
```

Comment: you are  seriously awesome.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's probably semantically better to add an 'odd' class and have the css handle changing the background. It makes it easier for people to maintain, as all the styles are in the css files, and all the logic is in the js files.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Myles' answer, you can use css3 selectors to select odd elements.

`li.comment:nth-child(2) { background:gray; }`

It's supported in most modern browsers except for IE8 (IE9 is supposed to support it though.)

Comment: Oops, just noticed that it needs to work for nested `<li>`'s. My answer won't work with that as it only works on sibling elements.

Comment: np, I've already solved the thing... :)  Thanks for the help!